# What is Project node in execution query plan?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the meaning of `Project` node in Sparks execution plan?
I have a plan containing the following:

```
+- Project [dm_country#population#6a1ad864-235f-4761-9a6d-0ca2a2b40686#834, dm_country#population#country#839, population#17 AS dm_country#population#population#844]
   +- Project [dm_country#population#6a1ad864-235f-4761-9a6d-0ca2a2b40686#834, country#12 AS dm_country#population#country#839, population#17]
      +- Project [6a1ad864-235f-4761-9a6d-0ca2a2b40686#22 AS dm_country#population#6a1ad864-235f-4761-9a6d-0ca2a2b40686#834, country#12, population#17]
         +- RepartitionByExpression [country#12], 1000
            +- Union
               :- Project [ind#7 AS 6a1ad864-235f-4761-9a6d-0ca2a2b40686#22, country#12, population#17]
               :  +- Project [ind#7, country#12, population#2 AS population#17]
               :     +- Project [ind#7, country#1 AS country#12, population#2]
               :        +- Project [ind#0 AS ind#7, country#1, population#2]
               :           +- Relation[ind#0,country#1,population#2] JDBCRelation(schema_dbadmin.t_350) [numPartitions=100]
               +- LogicalRDD [ind#45, country#46, population#47]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NOTE: Since the plan uses `RepartitionByExpression` node it must be a logical query plan.

---

[Project](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L49) node in a logical query plan stands for `Project` unary logical operator and is created whenever you use some kind of projection explicitly or implicitly.

Quoting Wikipedia's [Projection (relational algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)):

> In practical terms, it can be roughly thought of as picking a subset of all available columns.

A `Project` node can appear in a logical query plan explicitly for the following:

1. Dataset operators, i.e. `joinWith`, `select`, `unionByName`
2. `KeyValueGroupedDataset` operators, i.e. `keys`, `mapValues`
3. SQL's `SELECT` queries

A `Project` node can also appear **analysis** and **optimization** phases.

In Spark SQL, the Dataset API gives the high-level operators, e.g. `select`, `filter` or `groupBy`, that ultimately build a Catalyst logical plan of a structured query. In other words, this simple-looking [Dataset.select](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1252) operator is just to create a `LogicalPlan` with `Project` node.

```
val query = spark.range(4).select("id")
scala> println(query.queryExecution.logical)
'Project [unresolvedalias('id, None)]
+- Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

(You could have used `query.explain(extended = true)` for the above but that would have given you all the 4 plans which may have hidden the point)

You could have a look at the code of `Dataset.select` operator.

```
def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame = withPlan {
  Project(cols.map(_.named), logicalPlan)
}
```

This simple-looking `select` operator is a mere wrapper around Catalyst operators to build a Catalyst tree of logical operators that gives a logical plan.

**NOTE** What's nice about Spark SQL's Catalyst is that it uses this recursive [LogicalPlan](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan.scala) abstraction that represents an logical operator or a tree of logical operator.

**NOTE** The same applies to the good ol' SQL where after being parsed the SQL text is transformed to a AST of logical operators. See the example below.

`Project` can come and go since projection is for the number of columns in the output and may or may not appear in your plans and queries.

### Catalyst DSL

You can use Spark SQL's **Catalyst DSL** (in `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl` package object) for constructing Catalyst data structures using Scala implicit conversions. That could be very useful if you are into Spark testing.

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.plans._  // <-- gives table and select
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.expressions.star
val plan = table("a").select(star())
scala> println(plan.numberedTreeString)
00 'Project [*]
01 +- 'UnresolvedRelation `a`
```

### Good ol' SQL

```
scala> spark.range(4).createOrReplaceTempView("nums")

scala> spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
|        |     nums|       true|
+--------+---------+-----------+


scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM nums").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=8)

scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM nums").explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `nums`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
Project [id#40L]
+- SubqueryAlias nums
   +- Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*Range (0, 4, step=1, splits=8)
```

Comment: I think I'll include more examples to give you a better understanding of where and how it works. Stay tuned. And thanks for accepting it already!

Comment: BTW, Can you share the query you used and the command to output the plan? I'm reproducing your example but would appreciate some help if possible.

Comment: Hi @jacek-laskowski - this is super useful, thanks.  

I wondered if it might be useful to add the following to your answer, which I think would help newbies like me, but  I'm not enough of a Spark expert to know whether it's actually correct:  "The term 'projection' comes from relational algebra, can be 'roughly thought of as picking a subset of all available columns' - see [here]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra))."

Comment: @RobinL Thanks! That really made the answer more complete and comprehensible.