# How to efficiently create a PySpark dataframe with only data from some hive-style partitions?

Tags: pyspark

My data is stored in parquet files with hive-style partitioning with two partition keys `source_id` and `year_month`, similar to the following structure:

```
/data/plandata/
├── source_id=1/
│   ├── year_month=2023-08-01/
│   │   ├── file1.parquet
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── year_month=2023-09-01/
│   │   ├── file2.parquet
│   │   └── ...
├── source_id=2/
│   ├── year_month=2023-09-01/
│   │   ├── file3.parquet
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── year_month=2023-10-01/
│   │   ├── file4.parquet
│   │   └── ...
└── ...
```

I want to create a PySpark dataframe containing only the most recent `year_month` data for each `source_id`.  The most recent `year_month` may be different for different `source_id` values (and will change over multiple runs of my code) so this must be dynamic.

An approach that works is to:

1. first create a dataframe with just the `source_id` and `year_month` and group by `source_id` taking max `year_month`
2. then use this in a join on all of the data

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
basepath = '.../test_data'

# prepare test data - just for example, in practice my data already exists
data = [
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'a-01-08'},
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'b-01-08'},
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'c-01-08'},
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'a-01-09'},
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'b-01-09'},
    {'source_id': 1, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'c-01-09'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'a-02-09'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'b-02-09'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-09-01', 'dataval': 'c-02-09'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'a-02-10'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'b-02-10'},
    {'source_id': 2, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'c-02-10'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'a-03-08'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'b-03-08'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-08-01', 'dataval': 'c-03-08'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'a-03-10'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'b-03-10'},
    {'source_id': 3, 'year_month': '2023-10-01', 'dataval': 'c-03-10'},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('source_id', 'year_month').parquet(basepath)


# reading in the data - this is the bit I need to figure out
df_recent_partitions = spark.read.parquet(basepath).select('source_id', 'year_month')
df_recent_partitions = df_recent_partitions.groupBy('source_id'
   ).agg(F.max('year_month').alias('max_year_month')
)
df_latest_data = spark.read.parquet(basepath)
df_latest_data = df_latest_data.join(df_recent_partitions, 
   (
      (df_latest_data.source_id == df_recent_partitions.source_id) 
      & (df_latest_data.year_month == df_recent_partitions.max_year_month)
   )
).select(df_latest_data['*'])

df_latest_data.show()

+-------+---------+----------+
|dataval|source_id|year_month|
+-------+---------+----------+
|a-02-10|        2|2023-10-01|
|b-02-10|        2|2023-10-01|
|c-02-10|        2|2023-10-01|
|a-03-10|        3|2023-10-01|
|b-03-10|        3|2023-10-01|
|c-03-10|        3|2023-10-01|
|a-01-09|        1|2023-09-01|
|b-01-09|        1|2023-09-01|
|c-01-09|        1|2023-09-01|
+-------+---------+----------+
```

So this works as expected, for each `source_id` I have only the most recent `year_month` data.

**My questions:**

1. Is this an efficient way to achieve my desired result?
   I'm assuming that a) in creating `df_recent_partitions` Spark is not reading in data from all the files (since I am only selecting `source_id` and `year_month` which can be determined from just the folder names) and b) that in creating `df_latest_data` it is smart enough to only read data from the files in the relevant folders based on the join, and skip the others.  But I don't know if this is what's actually happening.
2. Is there a way to validate my assumptions?  I generated the explain plans (see below) for `df_recent_partitions` and `df_latest_data` but don't know how to interpret them.

```
df_recent_partitions.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[source_id#39], functions=[max(year_month#40)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(source_id#39, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=449]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[source_id#39], functions=[partial_max(year_month#40)])
         +- FileScan parquet [source_id#39,year_month#40] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/content/drive/MyDrive/PySpark exploration/test_data], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>

#----------------------------------

df_latest_data.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [dataval#127, source_id#128, year_month#129]
   +- BroadcastHashJoin [source_id#128, year_month#129], [source_id#39, max_year_month#52], Inner, BuildRight, false
      :- FileScan parquet [dataval#127,source_id#128,year_month#129] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/content/drive/MyDrive/PySpark exploration/test_data], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(source_id#128), isnotnull(year_month#129)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<dataval:string>
      +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, int, true], input[1, date, false]),false), [plan_id=435]
         +- Filter isnotnull(max_year_month#52)
            +- HashAggregate(keys=[source_id#39], functions=[max(year_month#40)])
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(source_id#39, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=431]
                  +- HashAggregate(keys=[source_id#39], functions=[partial_max(year_month#40)])
                     +- FileScan parquet [source_id#39,year_month#40] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/content/drive/MyDrive/PySpark exploration/test_data], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(source_id#39)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have your dataset, I use my own dataset to mimick:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: long (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
```

This is my dataset, `ts` means unix timestamp. `year`, `month` and `day` are the corresponding datetime information. The dataset is partitioned by `year` , `month` and `day` column respectively. If I try to do the similar logic like yours:

```
df = spark.read.parquet(path)
df_agg = df.groupBy('year').agg(func.max('month').alias('max_month'))
df_agg.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[year#2], functions=[max(month#3)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(year#2, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=13]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[year#2], functions=[partial_max(month#3)])
         +- Project [year#2, month#3]
            +- FileScan parquet [year#2,month#3,day#4] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[mypath, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

To answer your question:

1. Even you indicate your column selection, it just triggers [Projection Pushdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58235274/10445333) to minimize columns that you have to select. It's inevitable that you have to scan the underlying parquet files to collect columns information, even you're reading the partitioning columns. You can validate it by checking your Spark history sever to see the query DAG. You should see columns and size of the files that your Spark Application scans, as your are using parquet as storage. Or you should see a [Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47527617/10445333) Node in your query plan `Project [year#2, month#3]` (not sure why you don't have it in your query plan, it depends the Spark version and platform you use).
2. I don't think it's a efficient way to achieve your goal. As in `df_latest_data` plan, you can see that your application involves 2 file scanning and 1 joining process. Even it automatically broadcasts your dataframe, it's still a heavy work load. To achieve your goal, as your just want to do some searching based on the path string, why don't just use `glob` module in file system or use Spark Context to get the file status in HDFS? It should be much much faster as it doesn't require any file scanning or file transferring.

-----

Edit 1 on 2023-11-14

`where` clause or `filter` will trigger the predicate pushdown to filter out the selected rows only, while `select(cols)` will trigger the project pushdown to return the selected columns only.

Based on your approach and logic plan,  your procedure should be:

1. Read all the partitions and select the `source_id` and `year_month` column only (trigger the project pushdown).
2. Calculate the max value of `year_month` based on each `source_id`
3. Read all the partitions again
4. Join two dataframes to return the desired output

In your step 1, you use `df_recent_partitions = spark.read.parquet(basepath).select('source_id', 'year_month')` to read all the pair of `source_id` + `year_month` combination, which means you don't have any predicate pushdown and scan all the underlying parquet.

Only when you call `df_recent_partitions = spark.read.option('basePath', basepath).parquet(basepath+"/source_id=2").select('source_id', 'year_month')` or `df_recent_partitions = spark.read.option('basePath', basepath).parquet(basepath+"/source_id=2").select('source_id', 'year_month')`, it will trigger the predicate pushdown to filter and select the only row that you need.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.  Why does Spark need to scan *all* the underlying parquet files?  Why not only the ones within the folders for the given source_id and year_month that I specify in my where clause?  I would have thought that predicate pushdown (I assume that's what you meant, and not projection pushdown) would push my "where" clause down to the file reading process.

Comment: Hi @teejay, I just updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, adding some additional info from further research:  There was apparently consideration of skipping files altogether if only the partition columns were being queried (which is what I thought the behavior should be).  However, as the Feb 08 '21 comment from Cheng Su in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34194 explains, it's possible that a partition contains files with only zero rows, so Spark has to scan the files themselves.

Comment: Further: even in order to do partition pruning, Spark must first build an InMemoryFileIndex (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596156/12309386 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113450/12309386).  So Spark scans ALL the files within the base path.